# How can'i print page number in reports

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-9

Im' using odoo 9 i have create a custom report and i have tried this code to print number of page in report but every time it shows only the word **page: /** without numbers  . Any help please ?
       `<ul class="list-inline>"
                                <li>Page:</li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="page"/>
                                </li>
                                /
                                <li>
                                    <span class="topage"/>
                                </li>
                            </ul>`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks good. If you look into UI/views/ and search for "report.external_layout_footer" you will see that code you mentioned is working. **I think you porbably forgot to insert an appropriate div** Take a look at this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="report.external_layout_footer">
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
            <ul t-if="not company.custom_footer" class="list-inline">
                <li t-if="company.phone">Phone: <span t-field="company.phone"/></li>

                <li t-if="company.fax and company.phone">&amp;bull;</li>
                <li t-if="company.fax">Fax: <span t-field="company.fax"/></li>

                <li t-if="company.email and company.fax or company.email and company.phone">&amp;bull;</li>
                <li t-if="company.email">Email: <span t-field="company.email"/></li>

                <li t-if="company.website and company.email or company.website and company.fax or company.website and company.phone">&amp;bull;</li>
                <li t-if="company.website">Website: <span t-field="company.website"/></li>
            </ul>

            <ul t-if="not company.custom_footer" class="list-inline" name="financial_infos">
                <li t-if="company.vat">TIN: <span t-field="company.vat"/></li>
            </ul>

            <t t-if="company.custom_footer">
                <span t-raw="company.rml_footer"/>
            </t>

            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Page:</li>
                <li><span class="page"/></li>
                <li>/</li>
                <li><span class="topage"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>      
</t>
```

Ok, now the possible solution - insert in the report `<div class="footer">`

Useful resources:

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-add-page-number-in-qweb-reports-in-odoo-74996

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/odoo-page-number-in-qweb-reports-129335

Comment: Thanks i have tried these  solutions before but they don't resolve my problem

Comment: this is weird. I am working now on the reports in Odoo9, had the same problem and fixed it this way. Have you tried to download and change some modules for reports?

Comment: i have created a custom module for report templates but i didn't change anything in the default report module

Comment: BTW what reports are you working on? Are you going to publish it on app store? I am too busy to do everything by myself - that is why I am asking :)

Comment: i'm trying to customize all the reports and i started with saleorder and quotation